# referencing a user-defined xsl:function using XPathCompiler

Tags: .net, xslt, xpath, saxon

I'm using Saxon HE's XPathCompiler class in VB .NET to run XPath queries against an XML file, and then processing the results. I also have an XSL with user-defined functions. Is there a way I can reference these user-defined functions in my XPath queries? I'm successfully referencing them from other XSLs, but unsure how to do it when I'm just executing XPath queries on their own from a Saxon XPathCompiler object.

Basically, I'm hoping there's some way in the following code that I can point at my DocOpsFunctions.xsl stylesheet and access the functions defined there.

Code:

```
    Dim myProcessor As New Saxon.Api.Processor
    Dim myCompiler As XPathCompiler = myProcessor.NewXPathCompiler()
    myCompiler.XPathLanguageVersion = "3.1"
    Dim myDocBuilder As DocumentBuilder = myProcessor.NewDocumentBuilder
    Dim myDoc As XdmNode = myDocBuilder.Build(New Uri("input.xml"))
    Dim myResults As XdmValue
    myResults = myCompiler.Evaluate("dof:lefttrim('ISTeams/Team'", myDoc)
```

DocOpsFunctions.xsl:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:dof="http://docops.com">
    <xsl:function name="dof:lefttrim" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace($text, '^\s+', '')"/>
      </xsl:function>
</xsl:transform>
```

Input.xml:

```
<ISTeams>
<Team>Team1   </Team1>
<Team>Team2   </Team2>
</ISTeams>
```

I'm aware of the ability to define extension functions using the ExtensionFunction interface, but am hoping to find a way to do this more dynamically, so that new functions can be implemented in the stylesheet instead of in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you declare the function as public with `visiblity="public"`, then you can use `fn:transform` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-transform) in XPath 3.1:

```
transform(map { 
 'stylesheet-location' : 'DocOpsFunctions.xsl', 
 'cache' : true(), 
 'delivery-format' : 'raw', 
 'initial-function' : QName('http://docops.com', 
 'lefttrim'), 
 'function-params' : ['  foo']
})?output
```

In the Java API you should be able to use http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XPathCompiler.html#addXsltFunctionLibrary-net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltPackage- to expose the functions in an XSLT package/stylesheet to XPath.

In the .NET 10.2 API you should be able to use http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/XPathCompiler.html#AddXsltFunctionLibrary(XsltPackage) to do the same in .NET, namely expose a function library written in XSLT to XPath.

Comment: Thank you! I updated my post to clarify that I'm using Saxon's .NET dlls, not Java. Something like addXsltFunctionLibrary is exactly what I was hoping to find, though, if it exists for .NET. I will also give the transform function a shot!

Comment: @ecoan, it seems with Java the method `addXsltFunctionLibrary` is new in Saxon 10 so it is not available with .NET, perhaps Michael Kay will give us some insight when Saxon 10 for .NET will be released and whether the method will be exposed in the .NET API as well.

Comment: The transform function works nicely. (And I noticed when testing it that my sample data provided an invalid input data type for the lefttrim function - oops.)

Comment: Hi, The soon coming Saxon 10 .NET release will include the AddXsltFunctionLibrary method as on the Java version. We never like to give timescales for our releases, but we hope the .NET version for Saxon 10 will be out in a months time.